# iOS: UIScroll View - prevent scroll on view touch

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, event-handling

I'm trying to respond to touches on views in a UIScrollView. I managed to get standard touches forwarded to my subviews by subclassing UIScrollView, but if I press down on the view, then scroll, then let go, the "touchesEnded" method is not called, so the view remains highlighted.

I would like to correct this behavior.

I was attempting to follow this guide to prevent scrolling when a view is tapped:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1404

One step involves setting a CGRect property to the frame of your view. When I attempt to do this, it says my subview's frame is (0,0,0,0). This is in -viewDidLoad, so the view should have been loaded by then.

-viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];

    //Here I attempt to get the frame of my subview, but it gives me
    //(0,0,0,0)
    scrollView.subViewRect=locPhoneView.frame;

    locImageView.image=locImage;
    locNameLabel.text=locName;
    locAddressLabel.text=locAddress;
    locPhoneLabel.text=locPhone;
    monHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mon:     %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:0]];
    tueHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tue:      %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:1]];
    wedHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wed:     %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:2]];
    thuHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Thu:      %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:3]];
    friHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fri:        %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:4]];
    satHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sat:       %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:5]];
    sunHoursLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sun:      %@",[locHours objectAtIndex:6]];
    closedSundayLabel.text=[locHours objectAtIndex:7];
}
```

Here are my "touches" methods.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.view==locPhoneView){
        locPhoneView.backgroundColor=[ColorUtility colorWithHexString:@"83d3f0"];
    }
    if(touch.view==locAddressView){
        locAddressView.backgroundColor=[ColorUtility colorWithHexString:@"83d3f0"];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.view==locPhoneView){
        locPhoneView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    if(touch.view==locAddressView){
        locAddressView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }

}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}
```

So I guess I'm looking for two possible answers:

1. How do I get locPhoneView.frame to give me the correct dimensions?
2. Failing that, is there a way to ensure that the "touchesEnded" method is called, even if there is a scroll between the beginning and the end of the touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what's your question exactly but looks like ScrollView delegates like scrollViewDidScroll: or scrollViewDidEndDragging: or scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: might help you. See [Responding to Scrolling and Dragging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

Basically to handle touches inside scrollview, you will need to redirect the touches to next responder which is your view controller in your case.

Comment: Yes, I am successfully directing the touches to next responder. But it doesn't behave correctly if you touch the view, then scroll, then release. "touchesEnded" is not called in this case. I am trying to find a way around this problem. I found a proposed solution in the link above, but I'm not getting the correct value for locPhoneView.frame.

Comment: Exactly in that case you need to use scrollViewdidScroll or one of scrollview delegate methods. When you touch the view, set the flag saying isTouchBegun, and either you must get endedTouch event of if you see this flag set in scrollview delegate methods, that means you touched view and then scrolled! Hope that makes sense.